# Access IP address of PODs via lookup on Ingress URL

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am learning Kubernetes and have deployed a headless service on Kubernetes(on AWS) which is exposed to the external world via nginx ingress.

I want `nslookup <ingress_url>` to directly return IP address of PODs.
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

#### Inside the cluster:

It's not a good idea to let a `<ingress_host>` resolved to Pod IP. It's a common design to let different kinds of pod served on one single `hostname` under different paths, but you can only set one (or one group of, with DNS load balance) IP record for it.

However, you can do this by adding `<ingress_host> <Pod_IP>` into `/etc/hosts` in init script, since you can get `<Pod_IP>` by doing `nslookup <headless_service>`.

[HostAlias](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/) is another option if you konw the pod ip before applying the deployment.

#### From outside:

I don't think it's possible outside the cluster. Because you need to do the DNS lookup to get to the ingress controller first, which means it has to be resolved to the IP of ingress controller.

At last, it's a bad idea to use a headless service on Pod because many apps do DNS lookups once and cache the results, which might bring a problem because the IP of Pod can be "changed" frequently.

Comment: This headless service name resoltuion would be done by a library which uses CGO dns resolver which doesnt cache any result. The service wont be accessed by anyone else via IP.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a “headless” service with selectors, then the internal DNS for the service will be configured to return the IP addresses of its pods directly. This is a somewhat unusual configuration and you should also expect an effect on other, cluster internal, users of that service.

This is documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#with-selectors). Example:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9376
```

Comment: thats what i did, but it didnt work. I am not getting IP address of PODs on nslookup <ingress>

Comment: Where are you running this `nslookup` from? Inside the NGINX ingress controller? Or from outside the cluster?

Comment: Outside. So are you saying from outside world it will give Ingress controller's IP?

Comment: Outside - I've no idea what your setup is, which is to say what the public DNS records for your ingress are. 

All my answer does is change the *internal* DNS lookup mechanisms within the cluster, so in this example, if there was a DNS look-up for  `my-service.default.svc.cluster.local`. 

If you want to change the external DNS, that's not something that Kubernetes does.

Comment: By outside I mean inside AWS VPC where the cluster is also running